# Could i Patent something in the USA, not being USA citizen?

Tags: patentability, usa, foreign

I want to Patent something in the USA,but i'm from Argentina.

Could i Patent something in the USA if i'm not from the USA?

Could it be done Online sending digital documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to Patent something in the USA,but i'm from Argentina.
>
> Could i Patent something in the USA if i'm not from the USA?

Yes , You can patent your invention in USA.

You have stated that you are from Argentina, Argentina is NON PCT country so you need to file directly through National phase.

> Could it be done Online sending digital documents?

I am not aware of it i.e., procedure to be followed without PCT.

Comment: what do you mean by PCT?

Comment: PCT stand for patent cooperative treaty which have 108 participating countries if you file application with one country the same application can be shared with all countries within 30 months from first filing, as Argentina is not participating country you need to file with the respective national offices.

Comment: For further reading refer https://www.epo.org/applying/international.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by international treaty, all counties need to treat non-residents no different from anyone else in the world. The U.S. has a method to filing electronically via a web site [EFS Web](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/applying-online/about-efs-web). Anyone in the world can file a national patent application in any other country.